# which eclipse core installation should I download to use install the plug-in TeXlipse?

Tags: editors, texlipse, eclipse

I want to taste TeXlipse. First of all, I must install the eclipse core downloaded from [the official site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

I am confused with which one I should install. :D

Could you let me know the correct installation? Or I can choose at random?

I just want to use it for supporting TeXlipse.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Eclipse for other purposes than Java development (Python, TeXlipse), and I found that the slimmest download that works for me is the "Platform Runtime Binary", sitting at mere 50 MB. Your plugin will pull anything else that it needs for installation, so quite a few plugins will probably need to be installed anyway. This guarantees, though, that no superfluous plugins will find their way into your system.

Hunt it down from the list here, for the currently latest version:

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6.1-201009090800/index.php

Since you didn't specify platform, I can't give you a more direct link. You will need to hunt it down from the rather long-ish list.

**Edit**:
It's a bit tricky to find this page from the start page. You need to go to Projects->Eclipse Platform->[Pick release/build]->[Find needed package]->[Pick OS/Platform]

There might be an easier way to do it, though.

Comment: I installed java runtime first. Then I attempted to install eclipse 64 bit because of my 64 win7. However, the installation file cannot be executed. So I downloaded again the 32 version and successfully installed now. Now I am downloading the TeXlipse... :D Thanks you!